# facebook api with Oauth for google app engine

Tags: django, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I want to post to user wall from my GAE app.
For twitter, I use tweepy, which I can use Oauth, post a tweet.

I am looking for any facebook api that can function similar to tweepy.